# an analysis exercise

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f : (a, b) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, and suppose
$(x_j)$ and  $(y_j)$ are two sequences of points $x_j, y_j \in (a, b)$ with $x_j → a$ and $y_j → b$.
a) Show that the sequences $(f(x_j ))$ and $(f(y_j ))$ are Cauchy.

My answer uses the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous : $\lim f(x_j)$ when $j$ tends to $∞$ is $f(a)$, and hence convergence implies cauchy.

My question is if there is another way to do this.

Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: F is not a priori even defined at a

Comment: Yes, you have to use uniform continuity.  No you did not use uniform continuity.  You used continuity at $a$, which is not known because $f$ is perhaps not even defined at $a$.

Comment: Just to clarify the previous two comments, your answer above is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the definition of uniform continuity. If $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a uniformly continuous function, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$|x - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$$
thus as $(x_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(a,b)$ (when you consider $(a,b)$ with the topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$) there exists $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n,m \geq n_{0}$, 
$$ |x_{n} - x_{m}| < \delta $$
then,
$$ |f(x_{n}) - f(x_{m})| < \epsilon \quad \forall m, n \geq n_{0}$$
in other words $(f(x_{m}))$ is a Cauchy sequence, which doesn't converge, since $f$ isn't defined in $a$.

Comment: thanks for your time !